# how to sort dictionary that has list inside it?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have following dictionary in python:

```
dictionaryofproduct={
    "name":["Magnetic Adsorption Aluminum Bumper Case For Samsung Note 8","ESET Nod32 Antivirus"],
    "price":[1200,212]
}
```

I want to sort the dictionary by list of price on **ascending** order like following:

```
dictionaryofproduct={
    "name":["ESET Nod32 Antivirus","Magnetic Adsorption Aluminum Bumper Case For Samsung Note 8"],
    "price":[212,1200]
}
```

**How can I achieve this using python ?**

Thankyou in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to keep the prices and names together during the sort operation.  This can be achieved by combining them in a list of tuples (starting with the price) that you sort and then assign back to the dictionary items:

```
dictionaryofproduct={
    "name":["Magnetic Adsorption Aluminum Bumper Case For Samsung Note 8","ESET Nod32 Antivirus","Other"],
    "price":[1200,212,500]
}

prices,names = zip(*sorted(zip(dictionaryofproduct["price"],dictionaryofproduct["name"])))
dictionaryofproduct["price"] = list(prices)
dictionaryofproduct["name"]  = list(names)    

print(dictionaryofproduct)

{'name': ['ESET Nod32 Antivirus', 'Other', 'Magnetic Adsorption Aluminum Bumper Case For Samsung Note 8'],
 'price': [212, 500, 1200]}
```

*Note: I added an "Other" product to clearly show that the product names are not merely sorted alphabetically*

Another approach would be to write two helper functions to get and apply the ordering from one sort to multiple lists of the same size:

```
def getSortOrder(L,key=lambda v:v): 
    return sorted(range(len(L)),key=lambda i:key(L[i]))
def applySortOrder(L,order): L[:] = [L[i] for i in order]
                                                
orderByPrice = getSortOrder(dictionaryofproduct["price"])
applySortOrder(dictionaryofproduct["price"], orderByPrice)
applySortOrder(dictionaryofproduct["name"],  orderByPrice)
```

*BTW, if you are not committed to this data structure, you should really consider changing it to a list of tuples or a list of dictionaries that keep names and prices together for each product rather than relying on names and prices to be at the same indexes. You could also look into pandas/dataframes if you want to use that kind of model.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using the price as the list to look for sorting.

```
initial_price = dictionaryofproduct['price'] # backup
dictionaryofsortedproduct = {key: [v for _, v in sorted(zip(initial_price, value))] for key, value in dictionaryofproduct.items()}
```

The idea is to iterate on the key/value, and zip the value with the initial price list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample to achieve that:

```
dictionaryofproduct={
    "name":["Magnetic Adsorption Aluminum Bumper Case For Samsung Note 8","ESET Nod32 Antivirus"],
    "price":[1200,212]
}

pair = zip(dictionaryofproduct.get("name"), dictionaryofproduct.get("price"))
dictionaryofproduct["name"] = [item[0] for item in sorted(pair, key=lambda x: x[1])]
dictionaryofproduct["price"].sort()
print(dictionaryofproduct)
```

1. aggregate/pack the values for both keys by zipping them so that a single name corresponds to a single price.
2. Use the **sorted()** function to sort the zipped values on the basis of prices i.e the 2nd argument(x[1]) and fetch the sorted names.
3. finally sort the original prices as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a list of product names, and a list of prices, and they're
supposed to match based on the position in the list. This design is very much
error-prone, and it also makes it hard to find a product's price.

I would start by suggesting a different design for your data, with a list (not
dictionary) of products, and a dictionary for each product with the properties
that you're interested in (name, price):

```
listofproduct = [
    {
        "name": "Magnetic Adsorption Aluminum Bumper Case For Samsung Note 8",
        "price": 1200,
    },
    {
        "name": "ESET Nod32 Antivirus",
        "price": 212,
    },
    {
        "name": "Other",
        "price": 500,
    },
]
```

Now it's very easy to sort on ascending price:

```
sortedlist = sorted(listofproduct, key=lambda x: x['price'])
```

The `key` argument is a function that will be applied to each product in the
list (represented by the `x`variable) to return the value to use as sorting
key, in this case the product's price.